# How does the triangle inequality have anything to do with relative entropy?

Tags: distributions, joint-distribution, entropy, information-theory

I am reading Elements of information theory by Thomas M. Cover, and Joy A. Thomas second edition. and on page 19, chapter 2, section 3, it says:

[image]

I am confused by the random mentioning of triangles.

Out of the blue, this sounds like a typo. I am starting to understand relative entropy and its dependence on probability mass distributions but I have not used any triangles in any of my proofs.

#### Why does the triangle inequality have anything to do with entropy?

---

I have copied the text from the image below:

> In the above deﬁnition, we use the convention that $0\log \frac00  =0$ and the
> convention (basedoncontinuity arguments) that $0log \frac0q =0$ and $p\log \frac{p}0 =\infty$. Thus, if there is any symbol $x \in X$ such that $p(x) > 0$ and $q(x)=0$,
> then $D(p||q)=\infty$.
>
> We will soon show that relative entropy is always nonnegative and is
> zero if and only if $p = q$. However, it is not a true distance between
> distributions since it is not symmetric and does not satisfy the
> triangle inequality. Nonetheless, it is often useful to think of
> relative entropy as a “distance” between distributions.

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the definition of [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance) in the sense of metric space:

> In mathematics, in particular geometry, a distance function on a given set $M$ is a function $d: M \times M \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ denotes the set of real numbers, that satisfies the following conditions:
>
> - $d(x,y) \ge 0$, and $d(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$. (Distance is positive between two different points, and is zero precisely from a point to itself.)
> - It is symmetric: $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$. (The distance between $x$ and $y$ is the same in either direction.)
> - It satisfies the **triangle inequality**: $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$. (The distance between two points is the shortest distance along any path). Such a distance function is known as a metric. Together with the set, it makes up a metric space.

It just says that we do not have $D(p||q) \le D(p||r) + D(r||q)$ in general. In fact, it is not even symmetric.